# Automatically open the datetime component from an ion-select modal in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic2

In Ionic 2 is there a way to automatically open the datetime component after an event like pressing the OK button in an ion-select modal?

So it will go directly from pressing ok to selecting/pulling up a time on the datetime component.

I have yet to find a solution to directly do this.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go

on your template:

```
<ion-datetime #dateTime style="display:none" displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A" [(ngModel)]="startTime"></ion-datetime>

<button (click)="openStart()"></button>
```

and then in your code

first create a reference to the datetime control:

```
 @ViewChild('dateTime') sTime;
```

then add your event code:

```
 openStart()
    {
        this.sTime.open();
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: I get "cannot find name ViewChild" error. What should I do?

Comment: is ViewChild imported ?

Comment: I'm new to this ionic. I don't know how to do it. Can u help me with that?

Comment: make sure you have this at the top of the ts file: import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

Comment: Is there a way to add a function to the "done button" in that datetime picker. Why I'm doing this is, I'm trying to create an app, similar to alarms app. So, when I select a time and click done, a new list should be created. How can I do it?

Comment: in angular 8, must use static parameter `@ViewChild('dateTime', { static: false })`.

Answer (score 3):

this is a bit late but here is a complete answer for this

first import viewchild and date time like this

```
import { ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DateTime } from 'ionic-angular';
```

then add those properties to your

```
mydate :any;
@ViewChild(DateTime) datePicker:DateTime;
```

then add the datetime component to your view

```
  <ion-item [hidden]="true">
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY  h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="mydate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

you can now call open on your datepicker

```
  this.datePicker.open();
```

also `console.log(this.mydate);` to ckeck your results