# Ionic 5: DateTime does not work inside SegmentButton

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I tried to place an `ion-datetime` element inside `ion-segment-button`. This was done to simulate a choice of date between "today", "yesterday" and a custom date. The code looked like this:

```html
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="dateSegment">
  <!-- Other buttons -->
  <ion-segment-button value="OTHER" color="primary">
    <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

However, the date picker did not show up when clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually implemented a workaround by opening the `DateTime` on button click via `@ViewChild` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253102/automatically-open-the-datetime-component-from-an-ion-select-modal-in-ionic2):

In template:

```html
<ion-segment-button value="OTHER" (click)="openDateTime()">
  <ion-datetime #dateTime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-segment-button>
```

In component:

```js
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild('dateTime', { static: true }) dateTime: IonDatetime;

  openDateTime() {
    this.dateTime.open();
  }
}
```